# Widget - Instalar automaticamente através do aplicativo

Tags: android, widget

Gostaria de criar uma funcionalidade no App para adicionar automaticamente o `Widget` da aplicação.

Quando o usuário clicar em um botão, insere automaticamente o `Widget` na tela inicial.

É possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível inserir o widget automaticamente, você pode abrir a seleção de widget para o usuário escolher a partir do clique no botão:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetID);
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, KEY_CODE);
```

Parece que vai contra algumas políticas do **Android**, pois isso abre diversas brechas de segurança sem o consentimento do usuário.

---

**Mais informações nos link's abaixo:**

[How to add a widget to the Android home screen from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100926/how-to-add-a-widget-to-the-android-home-screen-from-my-app)

[Binding AppWidgets to AppWidgetHost - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258579/binding-appwidgets-to-appwidgethost-android/7794568#7794568)

Comment: Não vejo problemas em negativar a minha pergunta... Mas o porquê negativar a resposta sem qualquer explicação? =/

Comment: Não entendi também, tanto na pergunta quanto na resposta.